# How can i solve missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' in django

Tags: python, django, backend

here is my views

```
 @login_required(login_url='login')
 def updateUser(request):
    form = updateUser()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = updateUser(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'base/update_user.html',context)
```

and my forms.py

```
class updateUser(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Responsible
    fields = '__all__'
```

what im trying to do is update an name and department in a company

```
class Responsible(models.Model):
 name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
 dept = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Comment: please add the full error

Comment: You named both the view and the form `userUser`, so `form = updateUser` will call the view. Please rename the form to `UserForm`...

Comment: @EMREDAL: as a rule-of-thumb, please add a `...Form` suffix to all your forms, this makes it less likely to collide with names of models, views, modeladmins, etc.

Comment: Stick to the naming conventions of the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) and things like this won't happen. There would be no `updateUser`. The class would be called `UpdateUser` and the function `update_user`.